# Tax duplication and incorrectly displayed

Tags: tax

Every now and then it seems I get a tax duplication issue. I ship within Canada so I have all provinces and territory rules setup for my taxes.

After a few purchases, what ends up happening is that the taxes for 1 province will be displayed multiple times and then sometimes display taxes for another province as well.

Example:

For the province of Quebec the TPS and TVQ are to be displayed, but for some reason GST-BC and PST-BC are being displayed and showing inaccurate calculations; however the calculations for the TPS and TVQ are actually the correct total.

[image: tax break down]

The other strange issue is that the same break downs are reflected under the Sales order leading me to the Magento database.

If I go into the database and delete all references to TVQ and TPS in (sales_order_tax) then all subsequent orders have the correct break down. Old orders that were not from the province of Quebec (TPS and TVQ) are lost however.

**What steps can be performed to keep this from happening?**

**Is this a known issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to the module [EM Delete Order](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/seamless-delete-order.html).

What happens is that while this module does delete the orders, tax information isn't handled correctly resulting in unexpected tax totals. By removing the module and deleting all of the tax information from the database, all orders going forward display the tax correctly.

I am no longer deleting orders, I simply cancel them.